# Detect iOS device's cancel event within Ionic 3 app

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Could you tell me how can I Identify the iOS device's `Cancel` button event?

***The use case is this:*** I need to send the user into a `home page` when a user clicked the `cancel` button on `Contacts page` as shown below. At that time user is in the `Contacts` page. Here I use [**Contacts native plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/). I need to detect the iOS phone's `cancel` button event. Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe to the error callback, as described [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#example-2)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you explain bit more about it? @Phonolog

Comment: You are using the `pickContact` method to get to the view on the screenshot right? If yes, the `pickContact` method offers an error callback, that you can subscribe to. Not sure if cancelling is handled as an error but it might be worth a try...